# button1.setOnClickListener(this); Causing NullPointer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I've been asked to open a new question.

I have a sliding menu showing fragments. On one of those fragments is a set of buttons which play audio when pressed.

The OnClickListener for the buttons is causing NullPointer errors in logcat and is crashing the application. Can anyone tell me why? The buttons are being referenced through the correct xml relating to the fragment so I'm unsure what's causing the error.

These lines are causing the problem.

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(this);
 button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**SoundsFragment.java** which has the buttons and code hosted on it.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class SoundsFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    public SoundsFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sounds, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    private MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sounds);
     setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
     Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
     Button button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
     button1.setOnClickListener(this);
     button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private Button findViewById(int button1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private void setVolumeControlStream(int streamMusic) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void setContentView(int activityMain) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
     int resId;
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.button_1:
       resId = R.raw.a;
       break;
     case R.id.button_2:
        resId = R.raw.b;
       break;
     default:
       resId = R.raw.a;
       break;
     }
     // Release any resources from previous MediaPlayer
     if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
     }
     // Create a new MediaPlayer to play this sound
     mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), resId);
     mp.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      if(null!=mp){
     mp.release();
      }
      super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

fragment_sounds.xml which has the buttons and ID's.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sounds_fragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="Play audio a.mp3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_1"
        android:text="Play audio b.mp3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: They were added by eclipse after not being happy with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sounds, container, false);
    Button button1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    Button button2=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this); 
    return rootView;
}
```

Remove this

```
   private Button findViewById(int button1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
```

And

```
 private void setContentView(int activityMain) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

And

```
  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_sounds);
```

in `onCreate`

Comment: Perfect thank you. I have the private button and private void bits because eclipse was not happy with the code I provided and wanted to add them. After changing my code with what you provided it works fine. Will select your answer as correct when I'm allowed.

Comment: @rossd do mark the answer as accepted if it helps by clicking on the tick next to the answer

Comment: Will do in about 6 mins! you answered so quickly I have to wait :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `button1` is null, that's why you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the notation `@Override` before `onClick(View v)`...

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
```